# how to fix "A non-null String must be provided to a Text widget." error in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am implementing a basic code given in flutter website [link]https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ValueListenableBuilder-class.html I am getting the error: "A non-null string must be provided to the text widget". The text widget is being given the value of the increment counter. So could you please help why the null issue is arising?

Code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';


void main() {
  runApp(MyHomePage());
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  final ValueNotifier<int> _counter = ValueNotifier<int>(0);
  final Widget goodJob = const Text('Good job!');
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title)
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text('You have pushed the button this many times:'),
            ValueListenableBuilder(
              builder: (BuildContext context, int value, Widget child) {
                // This builder will only get called when the _counter
                // is updated.
                return Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text('$value'),
                    child,
                  ],
                );
              },
              valueListenable: _counter,
              // The child parameter is most helpful if the child is
              // expensive to build and does not depend on the value from
              // the notifier.
              child: goodJob,
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        child: Icon(Icons.plus_one),
        onPressed: () => _counter.value += 1,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting the error because you are using the `title` String as the `AppBar's` title and you aren't giving it any value:

I have added a demo using your code as an example:

```
void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(
        title: 'My Home Page',
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  final ValueNotifier<int> _counter = ValueNotifier<int>(0);
  final Widget goodJob = const Text('Good job!');
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text(widget.title)),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text('You have pushed the button this many times:'),
            ValueListenableBuilder(
              builder: (BuildContext context, int value, Widget child) {
                // This builder will only get called when the _counter
                // is updated.
                return Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text('$value'),
                    child,
                  ],
                );
              },
              valueListenable: _counter,
              // The child parameter is most helpful if the child is
              // expensive to build and does not depend on the value from
              // the notifier.
              child: goodJob,
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        child: Icon(Icons.plus_one),
        onPressed: () => _counter.value += 1,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: getting differnt error: The following assertion was thrown building MyHomePage(state: _MyHomePageState#532de):
MediaQuery.of() called with a context that does not contain a MediaQuery.

Comment: I updated my answer with a full demo of your example,  you should have a `MaterialApp` in your widget tree.